# converting html symbol code before sql insert stmt

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to export some data from a SQL Express table to Access using VB.net. The data is correctly displayed in SQL as, for example, temperature with the small degree object and the letters F or C for Farenhiet or Celsius. The character is of course represented by ° = "&#176" in html code, which is what appears in my access tables.

How can I get the insert statements to correctly pass this symbol? I have thousands of records and this applies to maybe a hundred or so in each of a few hundred DB's I am running this conversion on.

I read the data from a Gridview an .aspx .net web page and then use an insert query with an Access OLEDB connection.

```
SQLString1 = "INSERT INTO tblFornStrings (Str_ID, Code, Str_Name, Srt_Text, Lng_Text, Alt_Text) "
                            SQLString1 = SQLString1 & "VALUES ('" & StrngID & "', "
                            SQLString1 = SQLString1 & "'" & Code & "',"
                            SQLString1 = SQLString1 & "'" & Str_Name & "',"
                            SQLString1 = SQLString1 & "'" & newText1 & "',"
                            SQLString1 = SQLString1 & "'" & newText2 & "',"
                            SQLString1 = SQLString1 & "'" & newText3 & "')"
                            '  SQLString1 = SQLString1 & "'" & tblSource & "')"

                            Dim dbCommand1 = New OleDbCommand(SQLString1, pConn)

                            pConn.Open()
                            dbCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            dbCommand1 = Nothing
```

These are the two fields that have the data, newText1 = Srt_Text, newText2 = Lng_Text
[image: Showing html codes in access table]

I have now tried to make this a parameterized query, having read that it would allow the string to be copied without an encoding issue. It did not work. Here is another version of the INSERT code using the parameters.

```
Dim SqlString As String = "INSERT INTO Strings (Str_ID, Code, Str_Name, Srt_Text, Lng_Text, Alt_Text) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, pConn)
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Str_ID", StrngID)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Code", Code)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Str_Name", Str_Name)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Srt_Text", newText1)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Lng_Text", newText2)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Alt_Text", newText3)

     pConn.Open()
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     pConn.Close()
End Using
```

The output is the same as is dispalyed in the graphic for the output of the first code block.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Either this is a trick question or a simple call to Replace function (before inserting an HTML-originated string value into SQL statement) should do the work, like this: **Replace(newText1, "&#176;", Chr(176))**

Comment: @Yarik, thanks for the reply, not a trick question. Your solution works great for one language. The issue is that the code needs to be able to support any possible language that may get added to the web site. So your code will work great for say French, and any all codes that have this issue. all the sudden though, Thai gets added or, Italian, and an entirely new set of exceptions occur. anyh idea on how to avoid having to go back and add the Replace stmts? thanks,

Comment: Hmm... it's been a long time since I had to deal with i18n issues, so I hope you'd forgive me for asking this: how exactly do different languages affect this problem? I thought that the problem is simply about so-called HTML-encoding: on the actual HTML documents, some characters are HTML-encoded and that's how they come out of Gridview, so you need to find a way to HTML-decode them before recording all the data into database. (to be continued)

Comment: In that case, one specific character could've been handled by simple call to Replace function; but if you need a more general solution, you'd have to find (or write your own, at least partial implementation of) HTML decoding function - the one that would look for any patterns like "&#(\d+);" and replace them with a character with appropriate numeric code... But I still don't understand why language is important here. Please clarify (perhaps by editing the original question itself ;-) if that's not too much trouble.

Comment: This project is intended to allow translations of a large number of text srtings into many different foreign langauges.

Comment: Let me try to approach it from a slightly different angle.. So you have some strings extracted from Gridview, and so far you were using those strings "as is" to build SQL statements (or to set parameter values for a parameterized database command). Now, what happens if, instead of using them "as is" you'd decode them first - e.g. by passing them to HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(...) method? (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.71).aspx for more details.)

Comment: @Yarik, that did the trick. the solution is now working.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Shall we make an answer from that last post in the discussion? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have some strings extracted from Gridview, and so far you were using those strings "as is" to build SQL statements (or to set parameter values for a parameterized database command). Now, what happens if, instead of using them "as is" you'd decode them first - e.g. by passing them to `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(...)` method? (See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more details.)